# xterm "No protocol specified Xt error: Can't open display"

Tags: debian, xterm

I'm running a small Java utility on Debian 10, let's call it *startup_util*. It recently stopped working - I'm trying to work out why, and how to fix it.

All *startup_util* does is automate non-interactive use of a windowed application, let's call it *gui_application*. *gui_application* was designed to be used by a human; it pops up modal dialogs, requires 2FA, etc. *startup_util* makes it easier for *gui_application* to be used without human interaction.

In normal circumstances, *startup_util* is triggered by a cron entry like:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * 1-7 export DISPLAY=:0 && /bin/bash /opt/sutil/start.sh
```

This format is recommended by the developer. The idea is it will attempt to start every 15 minutes, in case it has crashed for whatever reason. The `start.sh` script in turn manages startup of *gui_application*. There is some logic to prevent more than one instance. It all stopped working recently; there is nothing of much use in syslog. But if I run

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && /bin/bash /opt/sutil/start.sh
```

manually, I see:

```
No protocol specified
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0
```

I have done a lot of digging and Googling. All that is clear is that there are a lot of moving parts (xterm, X11, xauth, xhosts, xcetera) and my knowledge of all of them amounts to zero. What I'm looking for is a step by step guide on how to troubleshoot the issue.

What I do know:

The output of `ps aux | grep X` is

```
Debian-+ 709 0.0 0.2 649260 48656 tty1 Sl+ 09:58 0:01 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/116/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
user 986 0.0 0.3 707324 59720 tty2 Sl+ 09:59 0:01 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

Output of `echo $DISPLAY` is a blank line

The machine recently ran out of disk space. That is now fixed, but some of the posts I've seen imply that could be a factor.

Any help appreciated

Comment: That will run as root. Root does not have an X display running. It will therefore fail. Even if you run it as the user running X, you should not run it from crontab as cron does not know and will not care if an X server is running or not. When I say an X server, it should be running as a logged in user, not with just showing the display manager login screen. If you need to run the app periodically, then use the display managers provided system for such things. KDE has KAlarm which would work. I'm sure gnome has something similar.

Comment: @Bib thanks, but maybe I didn't make it clear enough: the cron setup given worked fine for months

Comment: Doesn't matter. You should not be running X clients via cron. Use the DM native methods.

Comment: It's usually an *authentication* problem, e.g., the user that you are using in cron does not have the credentials for the current user of the X display.  [This Q/A](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/can%27t-open-display-no-protocol-specified-using-gdm-4175462031/) mentions a way to manipulate the `xauth` information.